# Logging exceptions in asp.net core / kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The docs show how to set a page for when an exception occurs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling

But how do I record the details of the exception in a log file on my server?

Does kestrel log exceptions and errors anywhere by default or do I have to do this manually?

Are there any examples or documentation available?

Comment: take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging)

Comment: That article shows how to manually pass in messages to log.  How do I catch global exceptions and errors at the webserver level?

Comment: You could create a middleware which catches the exceptions, logs them and rethrows them. Just register it as the first one.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, ASP.NET core has the built-in logging, but it does not provide the ability to log to file directly. Instead, you need to use 3-rd party libraries. 
 The good news is that all three most common logging libraries are available already for .NET Core as nuget packages: [NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog), [Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog) and [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/).

This article has a good overview over them and provides how-to-use examples: [ASP.NET Core Logging Tutorial – What Still Works and What Changed?](https://stackify.com/asp-net-core-logging-what-changed/).

---

Then I suggest looking into samples in [aspnet/Diagnostics](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples) repo. It shows how to custom or built-in error Middleware, ExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package called [Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File](https://nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File) that adds file logging with a single line of code (`AddFile()`):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                      IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
```

From [this article](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/).